# Swap hard drive

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, hardware

Can I install Ubuntu on a hard drive using a computer and then use the hard drive (and boot the Ubuntu installation) as primary operating system on another PC?

Does Ubuntu auto-reconfigure itself on different hardware? On Windows OS it doesn't work..how about Ubuntu?

**Edit:** Just for info, I've just tried and all works fine.

From: 2nd gen Intel CPU, 8GB ram

To: 4th gen Intel CPU, 16GB ram, geforce GPU

Comment: I'm guessing there is no available drive in computer B to install on, correct? So what is the reason you need to install Ubuntu using computer A then move it to B... rather than installing the drive in computer B and running the installation there?

Comment: also, please clarify if you intend to mount the drive from an existing system, OR if you want to boot the drive as the operating system on the second computer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Ubuntu should automatically detect hardware changes, and configure itself on boot, however you might need to install necessary drivers and possibly a new kernel if there are significant differences (ex. 32/64bit cpu) in hardware.

You can also run Ubuntu off a USB drive.

Comment: Any hardware differences to watch out for that might be deal breakers? Like the installed kernel requires 64-bit or PAE, and the old "new" system doesn't support them? Video hardware?

Comment: The default Ubuntu video driver will take over if there any changes to video hardware are detected on boot. Honestly I'm not sure what will happen when moving from a 64bit to 32bit system, as I've never attempted it.

Comment: By "mount" I meant use it on another pc, as you thought. I edited the question